# Will a Windows Anytime Upgrade to Ultimate work on a non-activated copy of Windows 7 Home Premium?

Tags: windows-7, anytime-upgrade

Will a Windows Anytime Upgrade to Ultimate work on a non-activated copy of Windows 7 Home Premium?

Answer (score 4):

[Microsoft](http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en/w7install/thread/f3bc59c7-b534-496a-91b5-b94a33d5add9) says no. You must buy a license for Windows 7 Home Premium, (probably at reduced prices), then upgrade to Ultimate, which is not very surprising. Let me repeat that: Attempting to 'upgrade' from an unactivated copy is not possible. This is because you cannot UPGRADE from something FAKE.

Comment: This answer is wrong. The upgrade works even when the original system is unactivated, I just tested it (on a Windows 7 Service Pack 1 VM without any updates). (Not sure though if the upgrade key will actually activate the upgraded OS.)